# DNS A record host pointing itself

Tags: domain-name-system, linux-networking, hosting

Ok, so I have done a really stupid thing,

[image]

Basicly I pointed the A record host to itself, of course what I intended to do wasn't working doh. And I changed the host to "@".
**BUT** i was wondering what could happen if I left this in place.

**Why I am asking this** :
For multiple days every 12h my server disconnected from internet (all ports, even ssh). I had to hard reboot. Looking at logs after, nothing specific on linux, the server was just no accessible until I hard rebooted it.

I can't test this case anymore, and tonnes of changes where made in addition of this correction. So i'm not sure my previous problems was indeed cause by this stupidness or another one of mine.

**For info :** server is hosted on professional server hoster and is one bare metal (not shared).

**For info 2 :** Here the ip is made of random numbers

Comment: I don't see how DNS is the cause of this issue. If it were, surely a reboot wouldn't fix it. Why don't you fix your DNS record and see what happens?

Comment: Ask about your problem, not what *you* believe is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is really stupid there is a DNS provider allowing an IP address as hostname in an A record. While it is technically possible, in practice ICANN prohibits any fully numerical TLD, so an hostname (the owner part of an A record) can not be an IPv4, nor an IPv6 for that matter.

Your record won't be used by any software whatsoever so the fact it exists in the zone file has exactly 0 consequences.

Your server problems ("disconnected from Internet") has no relationship with DNS content.

PS: don't post images for things that are purely text content, put the text directly in your question.

Comment: Thx you, I won't post image of this type next time